# How to resolve Gdk-CRITICAL **: 17:13:03.280: gdk_cursor_new_for_display: assertion 'GDK_IS_DISPLAY (display)' failed

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu, cron

After an upgrade to ubuntu 20.04 i receive this error from a python script launched from crontab:

```
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused

(generate_clocks_graphs.py:4888): Gdk-CRITICAL **: 17:13:03.280: gdk_cursor_new_for_display: assertion 'GDK_IS_DISPLAY (display)' failed
```

Is there a way to understand better this error? I cannot find a solution
The oddity is that if i run manually the script, it works perfectly

Answer (score 3):

looking at the code I realized that I had not put the following lines of code:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')
```

after entering them, the script also works running crontab

thank you

Answer (score 0):

Matplotlib backend relies on some backend to actually render the plots. The default backend is the `agg` backend. This backend only renders PNGs. [Docs for Matplotlib backend](https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/explain/backends.html)

```
#Three lines to make our compiler able to draw:
import sys
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')

import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')

df.plot()
plt.show()
#Two  lines to make our compiler able to draw:
plt.savefig(sys.stdout.buffer)
sys.stdout.flush()
```

This code is executed in [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/python/pandas/trypandas.asp?filename=demo_pandas_plot)